# Does Windows 7 always report it is on C Drive? How can I make it say it is on another drive letter?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I am setting up a multi-boot windows 7 PC, and I have read things that seem to imply that whichever windows 7 OS partition I boot up, it will always say it is on C- Drive [by default]?  Is this true?

What I want is each OS to report it is located on a drive letter that matches the partition sequence.  That is, if my HDD is partitioned like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Primary 1 || Primary 2 || Primary 3 || Extd Logical 1 || Extd Logical 2|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OS_0        Win7_1       Win7_2
```

I would like Win7_1, which is on the 2nd primary partition, to say it is on D drive when it is booted.
Likewise, Win7_2 would say it is on E drive.  And OS_0 would say it is on C drive.
That way, no matter what OS I am in C-drive will always be OS_0, D-drive always Win7_1 and E-drive will always be Win7_2.

Can this be done, and if so how?

Comment: The OS (Windows) you boot into will always report itself as C. Some info about changing drive letters http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2151725/drive-letters-dual-boot.html - **when in each OS you will still (and always) see the OS itself as C.**

Comment: I was afraid of that, though it is not true for old windows OSes like XP.  I had 2 XP installs on C drive (primary partition) and D drive (logical partition).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by altering the relevant keys in the registry (HKLM\System\MountedDevices).
For Example, if you switch between the values of "\DosDevices\C:" and :\DosDevices\E:" then next reboot the drives letters would be shown as you configured.
As Rysa wrote, you'll need to configure each OS separately.

Though changing the drive letters is possible, I would strongly advise against it, because you cant tell which systems would be affected.

If you're trying to get an identical path for each of this partitions, then I'd suggest you use mounting points.
You can easily create mounting points for all three drives and put them in the root of all three drives.

OS_0

```
Mounting point 1 - C:\OS_0 - OS_0 (It's a loopback for consistency)
Mounting point 2 - C:\Win7_1 - Win7_1
Mounting point 3 - Win7_2
```

Win7_1

```
Mounting point 1 - C:\OS_0 - OS_0
Mounting point 2 - C:\Win7_1 - Win7_1 (It's a loopback for consistency)
Mounting point 3 - C:\Win7_2 - Win7_2
```

Win7_2

```
Mounting point 1 - C:\OS_0 - OS_0
Mounting point 2 - C:\Win7_1 - Win7_1
Mounting point 3 - C:\Win7_2 - Win7_2 (It's a loopback, but you need it for consistency)
```

Here's an example [how to create a mounting point in Windows 7](http://wiki.flexraid.com/2011/09/29/tips-mounting-your-drives-as-folders-on-windows/).

Comment: Hmm, although I am not doing any raid stuff those mounting points are something for me to mull over.  Thanks for that link EliadTech!

Comment: Still wish Windows 7+ would not pretend to be on C drive, no matter which partition it was on.  So I might try the \DosDevices technique to see if I can get Windows 7 to report that its on a non-'C drive' drive.  Hopefully W7 coders don't hard-code "C drive" in their software somewhere.  I assume that is what you are concerned about when you say _"Though changing the drive letters is possible, I would strongly advise against it, because you cant tell which systems would be affected."._